# Unobtrusive Javascript UI test with webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webdriver

I'm testing the Javascript part of the UI using rspec webdriver (`describe "when blah", js: true do`) and have the tests running automatically with autotest. The problem is that the browser opens with focus disrupting my work. How can I make it open the browser in an unobtrusive way? In case it helps I'm running Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by ditching WebDriver and using [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/):

Poltergeist is a driver for [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara). It allows you to run your Capybara tests on a headless [WebKit](http://webkit.org/) browser, provided by [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/).